# Angular component Jade is not converting to html element

Tags: angularjs, pug

I have created the node js with angular application using Jade template engine. I'm trying to access the jade template into the angular component but it is rendering like string.

**Angular Js component**

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var module = angular.module("neela", []);

module.component("neelaList", {
    templateUrl: "home.jade",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: function() {
        var self= this;
        self.message = "Hello Neela!!"

        self.changeMessage= function() {
            self.message ="Changed"
        }
    }
});

}());
```

**index/home page**

```
extends layout
block content
header.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.static-top.sb-navbar        
    a(href="#").navbar-brand NEELA
    .navbar-nav-scroll
        ul.navbar-nav.pull-right
            li 
                a(href="#") Why Neela?          

neela-list  /* component declaration */
```

**home.jade**

```
    button(ng-click="changeMessage();")
```

Trying to load the button element into the neela-list component but some reason it is rendering as string instead the button.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to render `jade` into `html`.In separate file

```
module.exports = function(app){
  app.get('/yourTemplateURLInComponent', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home.jade');
  });
}
```